# Joining of Multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

1. comitees [ID, Name, Total_Amount, Total_Members, Starting_Date, Ending_Date]
2. committee_group [Id, Name, Total_Members]
3. Group_Member [Id, Group_Id, Member_Name, Contribution]

I want to select Name from committee_group Where sum of Contribution from Group_Member is equal to Total_Amount from comitees

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT committee_group.*, Sum(Case When group_member.Group_Id='1'
                                   THEN group_member.Contribution
                                   ELSE 0 END) 
FROM committee_group
  LEFT JOIN group_member ON group_member.Id = committee_group.Id
  LEFT join comitees ON group_member.Contribution = comitees.Total_Amount
```

Comment: You need a GROUP BY here since you do SUM.

Comment: from your explanation, it's not clear why you need the sum. you wrote you need just the names, no? and why the condition there for id=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work,

```
SELECT a.id,a.Name,a.Total_Members,c.Total_Amount
FROM committee_Group a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name,sum(Contribution) as 'Sum_Con'
            FROM Group_Member
            GROUP BY Name)b on a.Id=b.Id
INNER JOIN comitees c on c.Total_Amount=b.Sum_Con
                     and b.Name=c.Name
```

Comment: It return 0 rows as I have Total_Amount=30000 and contribution column have 3 data f 10000 each which is equal to 30000 but it returns 0 rows can you tell me why this so??

Comment: try now, the group by should be on the name field insted of the ID